# Word that means a stubborn problem-tackler?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word that means the kind of person who eagerly and stubbornly tackles challenging problems, even though he/she may not be at all suitable for the task? I am looking for a word that characterizes this kind of person in more of a negative light. (For example, this word can accurately represent a knight, for example, who lacks training, experience, and equipment yet decides to take on a mighty dragon alone) (Or a student, who has no knowledge or experience or talent in a subject, yet decides to take the most advanced course on that subject) Basically someone who does not know when to back down.

Comment: (Over) Eager, zealous, excitable

Comment: Related to: stupid, young, reckless, foolish, careless

Answer (score 2):

I"m not sure whether you're looking only for a noun, or could use an adjective - but perhaps hubristic, improvident, profligate might help. I came across "dunderhead" or "dunderpate" which have a certain appeal.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest *know-all*, as in,

- Fred is an infuriating KNOW-ALL; he is forever giving us his opinion on subjects that he knows nothing about.

> **Know-all:** (noun) Someone who thinks he knows everything and refuses to accept advice or information from others. (The Free Dictionary - online)

Comment: *know-it-all* is the North American version; I have never seen *know-all*.

Answer (score 0):

This is slang, but how about **Rudy**? If you've seen the [movie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rudy_(film)) [Wikipedia], you would understand that it's main character, Rudy, is "the kind of person who eagerly and stubbornly tackles challenging problems, even though he/she may not be (in the movie, *is not*) at all suitable for the task (*lacking a speck of football talent*)."

From the Urban Dictionary:

> [**Rudy**](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Rudy&defid=2673125): a person who gives it their all just like Rudy in the movie Rudy. A
>   person who will get pwnd [owned] and get right back up and get some
>   more.

While one can't help considering the "Rudy" in the movie heroic (he was, in a way), in reality one typically views such characters as almost insane. In that sense, the term ***Rudy** has negative connotations. **Rudy** certainly exemplifies:

- "a knight, for example, who lacks training, experience, and equipment
  yet decides to take on a mighty dragon alone"
- "a student, who has no knowledge or experience or talent in a subject,
  yet decides to take the most advanced course on that subject."

A **Rudy** is without a doubt "someone who does not know when to back down."

Comment: A "Rudy" might equally be described as a "dickhead" (BE). No allusion intended to your good self, Richard.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I prefer a word that is not slang.

Comment: @PeterPoint No offense taken. :-)

Comment: @Jon I understand, but that's too bad, because **Rudy** captures what you're looking for almost perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

that's a definition of amateur. 1 : devotee, admirer. 2 : one who engages in a pursuit, study, science, or sport as a pastime rather than as a profession. 3 : one lacking in experience and competence in an art or science.

from Merriam-Webster

You might also find use for the term "gung-ho," "bully-boy," "die-hard," "steam-roller," "ramrod," or "bulldog".

Answer (score 0):

There's a phrase that expresses your idea.

> Fools rush in where angels fear to tread.

And this often gets shortened to

> Fools rush in....

You could also talk about

> tilting at windmills

(This comes from *Don Quijote*.)

Comment: Isn't that tilting at windmills?

Answer (score 0):

I suggested **Rudy** in a separate answer, and while I believe **Rudy** captures what the OP is looking for, it's slang, and the OP would prefer a word that is not slang.

That said, when you boil **Rudy** down to its essence (or the real Rudy down to his essence), what you find is **dreamer**.

From Merriam-Webster:

> **dreamer**:a person whose ideas and plans are not practical or based in reality

While some true **dreamers** may realize their dreams, as the real Rudy did, many don't come close. At the same time, true **dreamers** don't give up -- after all, they're **dreamers** -- and because of that, "they don't know when to back down".

It's not hard to imagine characterizing the OP's "knight" or "student" as a **dreamer**, and to associate with it negative connotations. Many people think **dreamers** are in some sense unrealistic fools.

So ... it seems to me that **dreamer** meets all of the OP's criteria.

Comment: Might our dreamer be a Walter Mitty character? I think we should be told.

Comment: @PeterPoint Greetings, my friend. :-) SE is fun, isn't it. **Dreamer** is a solid albeit surprising answer. I surprised myself with it, but that's where logic led me.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an ***audacious*** person.

ODO:

> **[audacious](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/audacious)**
>   *ADJECTIVE*
>
> **1** Showing a willingness to take surprisingly bold risks. ‘a series of audacious takeovers’
>
> ‘Only someone really audacious would take such a risk.’
>
> ‘Troops and police have been involved in running battles with rebels who 
>   launched an audacious series of pre-dawn assaults.’
>
> **2** Showing an impudent lack of respect. ‘he made an audacious remark’